# How to replace variables strings with special characters in sed

Tags: sed, terminal

I started using sed to replace text in files, to make it easier to mass change the contents of files, and I have each value that needs to be set as a variable with BASH and the replacement as a function that calls all of the variables to replace the existing text. Example~

```
sed -i -e "s/$answer/$FORME $answer/g" ~$answer.txt
```

$answer is the variable input with the command in terminal. $FORME is a variable that is defined depending on the input of $answer, however $FORME contains "/" and I have been browsing online and can't find a way to replace using variables that contain special characters. When I try to use the command on $answer's that create $FORME with a special character displays this error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 15: unknown option to `s'
```

I'm assuming that means that the special character in $FORME is registered as part of the actual command, not a string to replace. Please help!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9):

You can use any character as a `s` command delimiter, so do, for example,

```
sed -i -e "s|$answer|$FORME $answer|g" ~$answer.txt
```

Answer (score 6):

Stunningly, this is asked and answered all over Stack Exchange, but the two generally useful answers to this very reasonable question are needles in the haystack. They are:

**1. Escape just 4 possible special characters in your variable**

As pointed out [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/255869/216323) (despite the question falling victim to the SE aversion to general questions), there are just 4 characters considered special in the replacement part of the sed `s` command: `\`, `&`, newline and the delimiter (usually `/` but can actually be anything).

So to use an arbitrary variable as a replacement in sed, escape any occurrences of those four characters first, like so:

```
REPL='Arbitrary variable potentially with special characters like / and & and \ and 
newline\
newline2'
REPL=$(sed -e 's/[&\\/]/\\&/g; s/$/\\/' -e '$s/\\$//' <<<"$REPL")
hexdump -C <<< "$REPL"
```

For example:

```
REPL='/&\ 
newline'
REPL=$(sed -e 's/[&\\/]/\\&/g; s/$/\\/' -e '$s/\\$//' <<<"$REPL")
sed "s/x/$REPL/" <<< "STARTxEND"
```

produces:

```
START/&\ 
newlineEND
```

as expected.

**2. Use an equivalent tool that interprets the replacement variable verbatim**

`perl` ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53429001/3697870)) has this capability because variables (provided they are part of the environment by exporting them or setting them in the invocation line) are first class citizens. Note `\Q` is not needed in the replacement string (but is useful in the regexp string).

```
export REPL='/&\ 
newline'
perl -pe 's/x/$ENV{REPL}/' <<< "STARTxEND"
```

produces:

```
START/&\ 
newlineEND
```

`awk`, despite [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20552191/3697870), does not.